# Unload a table from redshift to S3 in parquet format without python script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I Found that we can use spectrify python module to convert a parquet format but i want to know which command will unload a table to S3 location in parquet format.

one more thing i found that we can load parquet formatted data from s3 to redshift using copy command, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-load-listing-from-parquet

can we do the same for unload to s3 from redshift?

Comment: you cannot do that, would be nice though!

Comment: Thank you,jon scott. Do you have any suggestions to do it without python script?

Comment: spectrify is a great tool and makes the process quite painless. converting properly from csv to parquet is non-trivial

Comment: Thank you, jon scott. I will look into that. Can you share basic model how to use spectrify in python unload script

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/spectrify/ see "Perform all 3 steps in sequence, essentially “copying” a Redshift table Spectrum in one command."

Comment: Thank you,jon scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use AWS Glue or third party Python to unload Redshift data to S3 in Parquet format. The new feature is now supported:

```
UNLOAD ('select-statement')
TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix'
FORMAT PARQUET
```

Documentation can be found at [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered AWS Glue? You can create Glue Catalog based on your Redshift Sources and then convert into Parquet. [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-data-lake-foundation-with-aws-glue-and-amazon-s3/) blog for your reference although it talks about converting CSV to Parquet, but you get the idea.

Comment: I will look into that

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I have also blogged about few things to consider when you are trying AWS Glue for the first time as the documentation sometimes lack details in some cases. url below: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-top-5-gotchas-working-aws-glue-tanveer-uddin/